# Remove "time" dimension from RasterBrick R

Tags: r, time-series, raster

Given the following:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
s <- stack(lapply(1:3, function(x) setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))))
s <- setZ(s, as.Date('2000-1-1') + 0:2,name="time")
s
getZ(s)
```

how can I remove "`time`" from `s`?

The reason why I want to remove "`time`" is because I get errors while `cropping`a `RasterStack P` similar to `s`:

```
cr <- crop(P, extent(Germany),snap="out")

NOTE: rgdal::checkCRSArgs: no proj_defs.dat in PROJ.4 shared files

Error in R_nc4_def_var_float: NetCDF: String match to name in use
Name of variable that the error occurred on: "time"
I.e., you are trying to add a variable with that name to the file, but it ALREADY has a variable with that name!
  [1] "----------------------"
[1] "Var:  time"
[1] "Ndims:  3"
[1] "Dimids: "
[1] 2 1 0
Error in ncvar_add(nc, vars[[ivar]], verbose = verbose, indefine = TRUE) :
  Error in ncvar_add, defining var time
```

If "`time`" dimension is not the problem, what can be the solution to this error?

Thanks for your thoughts on this.

Comment: Strange! I found out that writing the the `rasterstack` to `.nc` and then using `brick` to import it suppresses the error. This is a painful process because I will have to write all files to `.nc`. Wish there was a simple way to convert `rasterstack` to `rasterbrick`?

Comment: There is a simple way, but can you please clarify your question? What is `P` (`show(P)`), and how did you create it? Is the file(s) available. Can you run the same code with `terra`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set a different name in setZ function. When you crop the raster, a new variable with "time" name is created, and the new rasterbrick cannot be created with two variables with the same name.

I had the same problem when I tried to export a cropped raster. I had to change de 'varname' from "time" to something else ("Date", for example).